# How to fix PermissionError: [WinError 32] with os.remove in python?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

There was a **PermissionError:[WinError 32]**  problem in my code. The file must be decrypted first, then deleted (encrypted). But the file is only decrypted and two files remain in the folder: encrypted and decrypted.

What could be the problem?

I already tried to delay between decryption and deletion.

```
def decrypt(file):

    file_in = open(file, "rb")
    file_out = open(str(file[:-4]), "wb")
    rivate_key = RSA.import_key(open("private.pem").read())

    enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = \
       [ file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1) ]

    cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)

    cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
    data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
    file_out.write(data)
    print(file + " DECRYPT!")
    time.sleep(5)
    os.remove(file)
```

**The following errors go:**

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/codes on python/decrypt.py", line 31, in <module>
    walk("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\codes on python\\papka")  
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/codes on python/decrypt.py", line 28, in walk
    if os.path.isfile(path): decrypt(path)  
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/codes on python/decrypt.py", line 23, in decrypt
    os.remove(file)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\codes on python\\papka\\data.data.bin'
```

Comment: You never close the files you open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must close the files before you can delete them

You must run:
**file_in.close()** before running **os.remove(file)**

This will allow the OS access to the file, as before python was holding the file.